# Problem Visual Studio with Parallels Desktop on MacBook m1

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly, apple-m1

I have a problem with Visual Studio. I have to type an application with one has client with graphic UI in c# and site calculation in assembly (with is connected to c# with dll file). I use MacBook with M1, so I decide to use parallels desktop to get visual studio, I started my project and I got an exception everytime with some dll problem, I decided to check my project on someone else PC with windows and everything was good. And there is my question is anything what can I do to solve this problem?

---

Exception thrown:

```
'System.BadImageFormatException' in LaplaceFilter.exe
An exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in 
  LaplaceFilter.exe but was not handled in user code
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
The program '[4636] LaplaceFilter.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)
```

Comment: please add error details to your question

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.BadImageFormatException' in LaplaceFilter.exe
An exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in LaplaceFilter.exe but was not handled in user code
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

The program '[4636] LaplaceFilter.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).

Comment: what dlls? Are they native ones?

Comment: Dll is created by normal dll project. Is it native one?

Comment: @Kromczetto maybe it has some dependencies? But a BadImageFormatException suggests something that the runtime did not expect